# Spring MVC <form:errors /> not showing error message from properties file

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, jsp

I was having some problem when trying to validate form in Spring MVC. Below as my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search.do", params ="doImageExtract", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    public String doImageExtract(Model model, @ModelAttribute("attendanceTO") @Valid AttendanceTO attendanceSearchForm,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {
        
        log.debug("doImageExtractSearchList(): bindingResult has error " + bindingResult.hasErrors());
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
            return "search";
}
```

In my JSP:

```
<form:form action="search.do" method="POST" modelAttribute="attendanceTO">
<table>
<td align="left"><form:input path="dteEnlist" maxlength="10" /></td>
<td align="left"><form:errors path="dteEnlist" class="errorClass" /></td>
</table>
</form:form>
```

In my TO class:

```
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private String dteEnlist;
```

And in my properties file:

```
NotNull.attendanceTO.dteEnlist = Enlistment Date is required.
DateTimeFormat.attendanceTO.dteEnlist = Enlistment Date must be in dd/MM/yyy format.
```

I tried to check bindingResult.hasErrors() in the controller and it did returned true. However, the error message is not displaying in the JSP.

I have imported validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar as library into my project.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit**

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/properties/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default if you keep the validation messages in a `ValidationMessages.properties` it should be taken up automatically without any configurations by spring. Keep your properties file under `src/main/resources` .If you are keeping the messages in a different file like `messages.properties` and using different keys for your validation messages then you could do like :

```
@NotNull(message="{validation.date.notEmpty}")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private String dteEnlist;
```

and also a configuration like when you place the messages in a `messages.properties` file :

**messages.properties**

```
validation.date.notEmpty =  Enlistment Date is required.
```

then provide the configuration to override default beans like :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

    // other methods...
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much! But can I check with you on how to bind the message to @DateTimeFormat? Because when I tried to add the message it gets syntax error

Comment: Also, I have the configuration as per the EDIT section in my dispatcher-servlet.xml. I manged to read some text label message from the properties file so the validation should be able to read from the file as well. However, it is not working still

Comment: @hyperfkcb I think for the DateTimeFormat annotation the default error message key for springboot should be like `typeMismatch=Please use MM/dd/yyyy format` in the property file.

Comment: Alright thanks so much! Actually I found another solution: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-display-validate-and-submit-form-example/ I tested and its working, the approach is to define the rejectValue and set it to bindingResult

Comment: But then that approach will render the annotation at TO class become useless